# Calculate liquidity of UniSwap v3 pool based on ticks

Tags: uniswap, defi, uniswapv3

If I mint position at T0 with the current Tick, upper tick, lower tick and position value (in USDC), how can I calculate total liquidity in the UniSwap V3 ETH/USDC pool?

I would greatly appreciate any help rendered!

Comment: Hello what is T0 , current tick , upper tick ? Do you try to get total liquidity of a pool ? e.g. ETH/USDC ???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.